# Numerical answer - differential equations MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Here's the code that I tried:

```
syms y(x)
Du = diff(y,x);
ode = diff(y,x,2) - (0.5/(x+1))*diff(y,x)+0.5*x*y == x;
cond1 = y(1.3) == 0.5;
cond2 = Du(1.3) == 2;
conds = [cond1 cond2];

uSol(x) = dsolve(ode,conds)
```

If there was a symbolic answer it would work, but I guess there is not. Could anyone tell me how to get answer for this equation?

This is the answer I get:

```
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.
> In `dsolve` (line 201)
    uSol(x) =
    [ empty sym ]
```

[image]

Comment: For this kind of problem, why don't you use [`wolfram alpha`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `ode45` or you can use a numerical method.

Either way you want to split your equation into two first order methods

u(x) = y'(x)

u'(x) = x - 0.5*x*y + 0.5*u/(x+1)

y(1.3) = 0.5

u(1.3) = 2

So doing it yourself...

```
function StackOverflow
close all
set(groot,'defaultLineLineWidth',3)

dx=0.01;
x = (0:dx:1.3)';
N = length(x);

Y = nan(size(x,1),2);
Y(N,:) = [0.5, 2];

F =@(x,y)  [y(2) , x-0.5*x.*y(1)+0.5*y(2)./(x+1)];

for i=N:-1:2                              % calculation loop
    k_1 = F(x(i), Y(i, :));
    k_2 = F(x(i) + 0.5*dx, Y(i,:) + 0.5*dx*k_1);
    k_3 = F(x(i) + 0.5*dx, Y(i,:) + 0.5*dx*k_2);
    k_4 = F(x(i) +     dx, Y(i,:) +     dx*k_3);

    Y(i-1,:) = Y(i,:) + (dx/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4);  % main equation
end

y = Y(:,1);
u = Y(:,2);

figure(1)
set(gcf, 'units', 'normalized')

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x , y)
set(gca,'fontsize',14, 'Position',[0.12 0.57 0.85 0.40])
xlim([min(x), max(x)])
xticks(linspace(min(x), max(x), 5))
xticklabels({})
ylabel('$y(x)$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')


subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x , u)
set(gca,'fontsize',14, 'Position',[0.12 0.125 0.85 0.40])
xlim([min(x), max(x)])
xticks(linspace(min(x), max(x), 5))

xlabel('$x$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')
ylabel('$y''(x)$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')

end
```

Or letting Matlab do it for you...

```
function StackOverflow2

%Note: t = xMax - x
[t,Y] = ode45(@F ,[0 1.3],[0.5; 2]);

z = flipud([t,Y]);
x = max(t) - z(:,1);
y = z(:,2);
u = z(:,3);

figure(2)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x , y)
set(gca,'fontsize',14, 'Position',[0.12 0.57 0.85 0.40])
xlim([min(x), max(x)])
xticks(linspace(min(x), max(x), 5))
xticklabels({})
ylabel('$y(x)$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')


subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x , u)
set(gca,'fontsize',14, 'Position',[0.12 0.125 0.85 0.40])
xlim([min(x), max(x)])
xticks(linspace(min(x), max(x), 5))

end

function dydt = F(t,y)

dydt = [y(2); (1.3-t)-0.5*(1.3-t).*y(1)+0.5*y(2)./((1.3-t)+1)];

end
```

Comment: Oh wow.. Thanks!  I am not as advanced in programming yet, so I dont understand most of it, and the code doesnt run as well, so I probably wont find the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In earliest Matlab versions, function definitions are not allowed inside scripts. Taking the answer from [@user1543042](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1543042/user1543042)

You should put this in one file

```
function StackOverflow2

%Note: t = xMax - x
[t,Y] = ode45(@F ,[0 1.3],[0.5; 2]);

z = flipud([t,Y]);
x = max(t) - z(:,1);
y = z(:,2);
u = z(:,3);

figure(2)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x , y)
set(gca,'fontsize',14, 'Position',[0.12 0.57 0.85 0.40])
xlim([min(x), max(x)])
xticks(linspace(min(x), max(x), 5))
xticklabels({})
ylabel('$y(x)$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')


subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x , u)
set(gca,'fontsize',14, 'Position',[0.12 0.125 0.85 0.40])
xlim([min(x), max(x)])
xticks(linspace(min(x), max(x), 5))

end
```

And this in another file:

```
function dydt = F(t,y)

dydt = [y(2); (1.3-t)-0.5*(1.3-t).*y(1)+0.5*y(2)./((1.3-t)+1)];

end
```